# power automate keyword not always triggering flow

Tags: power-automate

I have a pretty simple flow.   I have tried "mytest" in the test channel every 30 seconds since the last one fires.  as you can see, sometimes it fires, sometimes it doesnt.  the keyword trigger doesnt always fire. it seems sporatic. any ideas why?  What other info would you need to assist?

[image: My Trigger]

[image: Logs]

it seems like im hitting some type of limit.  i was able to make a bunch of keyword tests today and got expected results.  after a few test, it stops working again.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what plan are you on with O365?

Comment: M3 and Power Automate Per User plan.